# latLng returns null - Google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

Ok so here is the file. It was working some days ago. I haven't really changed anything so i do not know why latLng does not work now.

here is my code

```
function map_initialize() {

    var googleMapOptions = {
      center: mapCenter, // map center
      zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 10,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
      },
      scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
    console.log(map);


    //Right Click to Drop a New Marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
      //Drop a new Marker with location Form
      create_marker(event.latLng, 'New Marker', true, true, true);

    });
```

when i `console.log(event.latLng);` it returns an empty object.

Comment: I believe it should be event.LatLng (referring to google.maps.LatLng).  Lowercase latLng is not the same thing.

Comment: erm nop that does not work.

Comment: Where are you logging event.latLng?  [Your posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rf63L3mc/)

Comment: @geocodezip i was logging it below create_marker function.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rf63L3mc/2/)?

Comment: yep without the toUrlvalue(6) part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log(event.latLng.lat());
```

tried with `mousedown` listener , it works